# How to get a single key-value from JSON using ObjectMapper in java

Tags: java, json, parsing, jackson-databind

I have a json file called *file.json* which has a contents as following.

> ```
> [
>   {
>     "symbol": "AAPL",
>     "quantity": 100,
>     "tradeType": "BUY",
>     "purchaseDate": "2019-01-02"
>   },
>   {
>     "symbol": "MSFT",
>     "quantity": 10,
>     "tradeType": "BUY",
>     "purchaseDate": "2019-01-02"
>   },
>   {
>     "symbol": "GOOGL",
>     "quantity": 50,
>     "tradeType": "BUY",
>     "purchaseDate": "2019-01-02"
>   }
> ]
> ```

I need to get the values under the field **symbol** as a list as ["AAPL","MSFT","GOOGL"] in **JAVA** using ObjectMapper. Any suggestions as to how can I get the values in the symbol? For one single json entry I have found articles as to how map the values using POJOs using getters and setters. Can I do the same for this problem? How ?

POJO

```
class Stock {
      private String symbol;
      private float quantity;
      private String tradeType;
      private String purchaseDate;
      public String getSymbol(){
        return this.symbol;
      }
      public float getQuantity(){
        return this.quantity;
      }
      public String getTradeType(){
        return this.tradeType;
      }
      public String getPurchaseDate(){
        return this.purchaseDate;
      }
      public void setSymbol(String symbol) {
       this.symbol = symbol;
      }      
      public void setQuantity(float quantity) {
       this.quantity = quantity;
      }      
      public void setTradeType(String tradeType) {
       this.tradeType = tradeType;
      }      
      public void setPurchaseDate(String purchaseDate) {
       this.purchaseDate = purchaseDate;
      }      
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's done the exact same way as a single entry, only instead you use MyPojo[].class for the class argument... then it returns an array of your class `MyPojo`

Comment: If you don't want to create a POJO for this, you can use Jackson's [Tree Model](https://github.com/cowtowncoder/jackson-missing-manual/wiki/Chapter-Processing-Models-Tree-Model) API.

Comment: If you want to get fancy, you can use [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) to select only the fields you want.

Comment: The MyPojo[].class doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it.

Your JSON represents an array of objects. So, you can use the readValue method provided by Jackson and get an array of Java objects. This is where your pojo will come into play, since it will be representing the objects.

```
Stock[] stockArr = mapper.readValue(YourJson, Stock[].class);
```

You can then access elements in the array and call your getters on them.

```
stockArr[0].getSymbol();
```

To get all of the symbols simply loop through the array :)

Comment: @SomeshwarRoychowdhury can you post your pojo as well? This should work...

Comment: I have added the pojo as well. I had used int for the quantity first and then float as written here

Comment: @SomeshwarRoychowdhury and what error are you getting when you try my answer?

Comment: I am using vscode, it's part of a already built project and when placed inside a try catch block it moves to the catch block after encountering this line

Comment: You can see what exception is being caught then like this: ```catch(Exception e) {System.out.println(e.toString());}```

Comment: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Cannot deserialize Class com.crio.warmup.stock.PortfolioManagerApplication$1Stocks (of type local/anonymous) as a Bean
 at [Source: (String)"[
  {
    "symbol": "AAPL",
    "quantity": 100,
    "tradeType": "BUY",
    "purchaseDate": "2019-01-02"
  },
  {
    "symbol": "MSFT",
    "quantity": 10,
    "tradeType": "BUY",
    "purchaseDate": "2019-01-02"
  },
  {
    "symbol": "GOOGL",
    "quantity": 50,
    "tradeType": "BUY",
    "purchaseDate": "2019-01-02"
  }
]"

Answer (score -1):

```
@Test
public void testSymbols() throws IOException {
    String json = "[\n" + "  {\n" + "    \"symbol\": \"AAPL\",\n" + "    \"quantity\": 100,\n" + "    \"tradeType\": \"BUY\",\n"
            + "    \"purchaseDate\": \"2019-01-02\"\n" + "  },\n" + "  {\n" + "    \"symbol\": \"MSFT\",\n"
            + "    \"quantity\": 10,\n" + "    \"tradeType\": \"BUY\",\n" + "    \"purchaseDate\": \"2019-01-02\"\n" + "  },\n"
            + "  {\n" + "    \"symbol\": \"GOOGL\",\n" + "    \"quantity\": 50,\n" + "    \"tradeType\": \"BUY\",\n"
            + "    \"purchaseDate\": \"2019-01-02\"\n" + "  }\n" + "]";

     List list =  objectMapper.readValue(json ,List.class);
     List<String> symList = new ArrayList<>();
      list.stream().map( m-> ((LinkedHashMap) m).get("symbol")).forEach( o->{
        symList.add((String)o);
      });
      System.out.println(symList);
}
```

// output : [AAPL, MSFT, GOOGL]

Comment: My program shows LinkedHashMap cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: list.stream().map( m-> ((Map) m).get("symbol")).forEach( o->{
     symList.add((String)o);
    });

Comment: Try changing the LinkedHashMap to Map.

Comment: Not a very pretty solution

Comment: If going the List route, you should really use `CollectionType type = objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType( List.class, MyPojo.class )`

Comment: and then use `type` as the argument